# Insert and update a datetime into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, t-sql

```
private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtWedstrijdSchemaID.Text == "")
        {
            //Insert
            string SQL;
            SQL = "Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum)";
            SQL += " values (";
            SQL += "" + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
            SQL += "" + txtTeam2.Text + ",";
            SQL += "" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "";
            SQL += ")";

            clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
            vulLv();
        }
        else
        {
            //Update
            string SQL;
            SQL = "Update Wedstrijdschema SET ";
            SQL += "Team1 = " + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
            SQL += "Team2 = " + txtTeam2.Text + ",";
            SQL += "Datum = " + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "";
            SQL += " where SchemaId = " + zoek;

            clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
            vulLv();
        }
        txtDatum.Enabled = txtTeam2.Enabled = txtTeam1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

That is what I currently have, because of a trycatch it won't crash when I try, if I comment the txtDatum.Text out on the //insert and //upload it works (but obviously enters NULL for Datum in the Database) does anyone perhaps see where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: About the use of parameters, we need to use a threetier system where all SQL goes through a class which is the only one allowed to do anything with the database, this is how the command is executed:

```
public static bool ExecuteCommand(string SQLInstructie)
        {
            bool retour = true;
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(clStam.Connstr);
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLInstructie, Conn);

            try
            {
                Cmd.Connection.Open();
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                retour = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
            return retour;
        }
```

This works!! Thanks a lot for the help:

```
private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtWedstrijdSchemaID.Text == "")
            {
                //Insert

                string SQL;
                SQL = "Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum)";
                SQL += " values (";
                SQL += "" + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
                SQL += "" + txtTeam2.Text + ",";
                SQL += "'" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "'";
                SQL += ")";
                Debug.WriteLine(SQL);
                clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
                vulLv();
            }
            else
            {
                //Update
                string SQL;
                SQL = "Update Wedstrijdschema SET ";
                SQL += "Team1 = " + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
                SQL += "Team2 = " + txtTeam2.Text + ",";
                SQL += "Datum = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "'";
                SQL += " where SchemaId = " + zoek;

                clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
                vulLv();
            }
            txtDatum.Enabled = txtTeam2.Enabled = txtTeam1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

EDIT: I'll promise to use parameterized SQL from now on!

Comment: remove single quotes from datetime column values

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? it will depend on the format that the date is expected. Look into paramaters, they are much better than building SQL strings manually.

Comment: Use a parametrized statement, run your code with a `'` in the textbox and see what happens.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text)` will probably not give the correct format; it will become `19-6-2015 14:49:23` or so (ToString() is implicitely called). And because you are using a Dutch system, this depends on the culture setting (don't worry; I'm also Dutch). You need to know what your DB is expecting for the string and adjust the formatting.

Comment: Before `clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);`, please add the line `Debug.WriteLine(SQL);`. Check the output window. How does the SQL look like?

Comment: Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum) values (1,1,11-6-2015 0:00:00)
that's what the debug gives

Comment: The 3-layer 'architecture' does not really seem to encapsulate or abstract away any of the database in the datalayer: you are still writing SQL in your business layer. If that is part of the original assignment it is not a good example as to how to properly abstract away your datastore.

Comment: Where should I look for a proper example of how to do it in the future? This is what we made during school class so besides this I don't really know how I would do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a command `,` from the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement.

The syntax to insert data into the database is:

```
 INSERT INTO Table 
        (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
 VALUES
        ('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value3')
```

Aside that, you are vulnerable to `SQL injection`, use SQL paramerterised queries to prevent this.

I would first start off by using a `SqlCommand` object.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum) VALUES (@V1, @V2, @V3");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V1", txtTeam1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V2", txtTeam2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V3", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text));
```

And then execute it using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

As an additional note I would also ensure that the value in `txtDatum` is converted correctly to the desired date format.

Comment: This is part of a project for school, I'm aware I should always do it parameterised but I kinda slacked and didn't do it.

Comment: @StrahBehry - well this is a good chance to change the implementation, show best practices in your school project and hopefully get a better mark.

Comment: On it, even after your and Ameya's suggestions it still doesn't work. But I'll change it as you suggested above first and see if I just messed up the syntax.

Comment: Can you please look at the edit I made Darren, this is what we have to use in our database tier.

Comment: @StrahBehry - do you receive an error message? Does the the program flow enter the catch statement?

Comment: @StrahBehry - what does the catch tell you... Is it a FormatException for the date or is it SQL related?

Comment: Found it, tried the query in SQL managment studio that debug.writeline(sql); gave me and it told me there was an syntax error near 0:00:00 so I put quotes around the datetime and then it worked. Added single quotes in the C# code.

Answer (score 2):

remove single quotes from datetime column. also you missed column to add in insert statement

```
private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtWedstrijdSchemaID.Text == "")
            {
                //Insert
                string SQL;
                SQL = "Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2,**Datum**)";
                SQL += " values (";
                SQL += "" + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
                SQL += "" + txtTeam2.Text + "";
                SQL += "" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "";
                SQL += ")";

                clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
                vulLv();
            }
            else
            {
                //Update
                string SQL;
                SQL = "Update Wedstrijdschema SET ";
                SQL += "Team1 = " + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
                SQL += "Team2 = " + txtTeam2.Text + "";
                SQL += "Datum = " + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text) + "";
                SQL += " where SchemaId = " + zoek;

                clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
                vulLv();
            }
            txtDatum.Enabled = txtTeam2.Enabled = txtTeam1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I also noticed, that was from testing while not having the Datum added. It still does not work tho...

Answer (score 2):

Always use [parameterized](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) queries.string concatenations make a way to sql injection

```
private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtWedstrijdSchemaID.Text == "")
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum)  values (@Team1,@Team2,@datetime)"); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team1",txtTeam1.Text 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team2",txtTeam2.Text              
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime",Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text)     
     clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
     vulLv();
    }
    else
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Wedstrijdschema SET Team1=@team1,Team2=@team2,Datum =@Datum where SchemaId=@SchemaId");
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team1",txtTeam1.Text );
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team2",txtTeam2.Text);              
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum ",Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchemaId",zoek);
     clDatabase.ExecuteCommand(SQL);
     vulLv();
    }
    txtDatum.Enabled = txtTeam2.Enabled = txtTeam1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ToString` to format your date in an acceptable format (and enclose in quotes as it's being passed as a string):

```
string SQL;
    SQL = "Insert into Wedstrijdschema (Team1, Team2, Datum)";
    SQL += " values (";
    SQL += "" + txtTeam1.Text + ",";
    SQL += "" + txtTeam2.Text + ",";
    SQL += "'" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";
    SQL += ")";
```